# RemObjects: How do I set aRetry in clientChannelNeedsLogin on Android?

Tags: android, remobjects

As the title says, how do I set aRetry in clientChannelNeedsLogin on Android?

Answer (score 0):

As posted on [remobjects connect](http://connect.remobjects.com/discussion/comment/14113/#Comment_14113):

> It is designed that callback method should return TRUE if retry is needed, false otherwise.
>
> But if appears, that there is a bug in the processing of triggerOnLoginNeeded() callback, so that retry not performed even if callback returns true. It is already fixed in latest beta and will be included in upcoming release.

Comment: Hey. Yeah, thanks for the answer. I've just grabbed the new beta release and am trying to get it working, but I've run into a couple of problems that I'm trying to solve... I'll post them on connect